# FuelPHP - Перестал работать сайт при переносе на другой хост

Tags: php

Есть сайт написан на фреймворке FuelPHP, но при переносе на другой хостинг все страницы сайта перестали работать кроме главной. При переходе на страницу пишет:

> Not Found The requested URL " урл " was not found on this server.

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в .htaccess (либо в web.config, если виндовый сервер).

Comment: @A1essandro или обратная ситуация, переехали с апача на nginx, где .htaccess не действует